# Getting this error on Amazon Lex when trying to use slots:Invalid lambda response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Im trying to use lamba to build  bot on Lex. When i run the bot, it asks for the first and the second slot information then give me an error "An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled". Below is the lambda code. I am trying to pull information from dynamodb.

```
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var authSSN = event.currentIntent.slots.AuthSSN;
    var authLIC = event.currentIntent.slots.AuthLIC;

    var params = {
      TableName: 'cb_users',
      Keys: {
           "SSN4": AuthSSN,
          "LIC4": AuthLIC

     },
       AttributesToGet: ["userId"]
 };
    docClient.get(params, function(err,data){
       if(err){
         callback(err,null);
      }else {
         callback(null,{"dialogAction": {
            "type": "ConfirmIntent",
            "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
            "message": {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "Your account has been verified. You user id is: " 
                },
            "intent-name": "Welcome"

            }   
        });
        }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html), you should be using

```
"intentName": "Welcome"
```

instead of

```
"intent-name": "Welcome"
```